# Mono.when firing before publishers complete

Tags: java, project-reactor

Sample code:

```
Flux<Integer> fluxSrc = Flux.<Integer> create(e -> {
   e.next(1);

   try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
   } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e1);
   }

   e.complete();
})
   .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
   .publish().autoConnect(2);

Flux<Integer> fluxA = fluxSrc
   .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
   .map(j -> 10 + j);

fluxA.subscribe(System.out::println);

Mono<Integer> monoB = fluxSrc
   .publishOn(Schedulers.single())
   .reduce(20, (j, k) -> {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e1);
      }
      return j + k;
   });

monoB.subscribe(System.out::println);

Mono.when(fluxA, monoB)
   .block();

System.out.println("After");
```

This produces the following output:

```
11
After
21
```

Why does it not wait for both publishers (`fluxA` and `monoB`) to complete? How should I structure the code so I make sure all publishers complete before `After` is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.publish()`, `fluxSrc` is turned into hot flux. Consider:

> Hot publishers, on the other hand, do not depend on any number of
>   subscribers. They might start publishing data right away and would
>   continue doing so whenever a new Subscriber comes in (in which case
>   said subscriber would only see new elements emitted after it
>   subscribed). For hot publishers, something does indeed happen before
>   you subscribe.

(https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold)

One way to fix it is to get rid of `publish` and operate on cold stream. Another one is to change `.autoConnect(2);` to `.autoConnect(3);` - that's because you want to start processing data when 3rd subscription - `Mono.when(fluxA, monoB).block();` is reached (previous ones are `fluxA.subscribe` and `monoB.subscribe`).

**Edit**: 
`When` did wait for sources to finish, but it got onComplete signal from previous subsription.

What probably happened is:

1. flux A was subsribed by `fluxA.subscribe(System.out::println);`, emitted 11 and printed it.
2. flux B was subsribed by `monoB.subscribe(System.out::println);` and started reduction.
3. `Mono.when` was subsribed (which triggered "multicasting" - fluxes were subsribed second time).
4. Reduction started, it's result will be 21.
5. Another reduction started and was immediately finished with result 20 (reducing empty stream - only item from fluxSrc was already consumed by another reduction).
6. flux A sent onComplete to both subsribers.
7. flux B sent onComplete with result of reduction = 20. It was passed to subscription made by `Mono.when`, that's why it wasn't printed.
8. Both fluxes sent onComplete since Mono.when subsription, so that `After` was printed.
9. Around that time first reduction was completed with value 21, which was passed to `monoB.subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: So `fluxSrc` is a hot flux and potentially publishes before `block` is subscribed. Can you clarify why would that make `when` not wait for both `fluxA` and `monoB` to finish?

Comment: Thats because of race condition. If you just expect to have 'after' printed as a last statement, you have to synchronize threads of reactor schedulers and application.

Also OnComplete signal is broadcasted to every subscriber, on my machine it looks like that:

completed flux a;
completed mono b;
completed flux a <-this subscription comes from Mono.when();
After;
completed mono b <-this subscription comes from Mono.when();

Adding `Thread.sleep(2000);` just before Mono.when() blocks indefinitely, because both onComplete signals happen before Mono.when() subscribes.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why `when` would not wait for both its sources to finish. Weren't reactive streams made exactly so users would not have to worry about threading and race conditions? Having the program behave differently when you put `Thread.sleep` before `when` is not really encouraging.

Comment: Not sure where you get steps 4 and 8 - the reduction produces a `Mono`, so it cannot emit twice. `monoB` will emit at most one result and it must emit it before it completes, right?

Comment: Indeed, B must have completed after reduction - I corrected the order.
Reduction of Mono with inital value 20 and current value 1 produces 21 and completes the Mono. Reduction of already completed fluxSrc(which is the base of Mono B) with initial value 20 produces 20. That means, in this case MonoB will emit exactly one item, but due to multicasting to multiple subsribers, result of reduction of this mutlticasted item will vary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196492/discussion-between-szurawar-and-levant-pied).